# How to pass redirect symbols (< and >) to a Windows batch file function?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Assume this batch file

```
call :SomeFunction "a string with an > arrow"

goto:eof

:SomeFunction
  echo %~1
goto:eof
```

The output of this is

```
call :SomeFunction "a string with an > arrow"
echo a string with an  1>arrow
goto:eof
goto:eof
```

and a file named `arrow` is created which contains `a string with an`. Note the `1>`.

How can I prevent the command processor from interpreting the `>` as a redirection symbol in this situation? (Hint: I've tried `^>` and that's not it.)

EDIT: The other operators (`|` and `&`) are of course also affected.

Comment: Here are some good examples of redirection in batch files. http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `FOR /F` command for that, instead of:

```
echo %~1
```

Use this:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ("%~1") DO echo %%i
```

**Edit:** note that now you need to deal with strange escaping behaviors when you pass an argument delimited with double quotes. For example `"a^2"` will be *escaped* as `"a^^2"`, no matters if you try with `"a^^2"` or `"a\^2"`. What you may do (from your own comment) is to use a temporary variable and do escaping (then removing double quotes):

```
set TEMP=%TEMP:>=^>%
```

If you do not want to care about escaping you may also try:

```
set "tmp="many \ ^ > ' characters and quotes""
```

Note double quotes to enclose `set` argument and many *special* characters in the string. In this case `tmp` environment variable will literally be: `"many \ ^ > ' characters and quotes"`, you can simply use it as:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%1 IN (%tmp%) DO echo %%1
```

Note `%1` instead of `"%~1"`. Let's now make it more complicated. If you need double quotes <kbd>"</kbd> inside your string then some characters won't be escaped (<kbd>&</kbd> and <kbd>|</kbd> for example). You may simply remove quotes:

```
set "tmp=many \ ^ > ' | & characters and quotes"
```

Used:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%1 IN ("%tmp%") DO echo %%1
```

Or

```
FOR /F "delims== tokens=2" %%1 IN ('set tmp') DO echo %%1
```

Don't forget you can use backtips to delimit `FOR` string if you specify `usebackq` option. You may use a temporary file or...better...a PowerShell script...

Comment: Brilliant, this works. It doubles escape characters (`^`) that might be in the string, though...

Comment: @Tomalak yes, call is terrible for escaping its parameters (so you may need (%1) instead of ("%~1")) anyway _some_ characters need to be escaped. AFAIK there isn't a true "raw" way to pass a parameter without escaping (unless you use a temporary file).

Comment: `Call` is doubling the escape characters.  That's the funky bit.

Comment: @foxidrive yes, string you pass to call must be properly escaped (with exception of double quotes which aren't supported here).

Comment: The behavior of `cmd.exe` is nothing short of madness. Maybe I'm missing a big piece of the puzzle, but the way all of this works when you leave the "just a bunch of sequential statements" territory makes my brain hurt.

Comment: @Tomalak I agree. It has been extended without any coherence and with a lot of holes and dark corners (compatibility?). THat's why I love PS!

Comment: I suppose I could use `%1`, assign it to a TEMP variable, substitute `>` with `^>` (`set TEMP=%TEMP:>=^>%`) and remove enclosing quotes (`%TEMP:~1,-1%`) if there are quotes and then `echo %TEMP%`. This... uhhh... works, but it eats my sanity.

Comment: @Tomalak not only, you can skip escaping and keep `FOR` if you set temp variable with `set "tmp="many \ ^ > ' characters and quotes""` (note double quotes at beginning and end and inner quotes for _value_).

Comment: I'd upvote you again for your edit, if I could. Very enlightening!

Answer (score 1):

`Call` does funky things with `^` but this works.

```
@echo off
set "var=a string with an ^> arrow"
call :SomeFunction 
pause
goto:eof

:SomeFunction
  echo %var%
goto:eof
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's not the solution. I wanted to keep using function arguments (instead of global variables)

Comment: +1 It's not the best solution, but it shows how to solve the problem in a general way

Answer (score 1):

Like foxidrive mentioned, CALL will modify carets, so it's not possible to build a bullet proof way to transfer parameters by value via CALL.
But you can use parameters by reference instead.

```
@echo off
set "var=a string with a caret^ and an > arrow"

call :SomeFunc var
exit /b

:SomeFunc
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "param1=!%1!"
echo !param1!
exit /b
```

I use here delayed expansion, as this is the best way to handle any variable content in a safe way