# BATCH - Working with string(< , >) instead of redirection

Tags: string, batch-file, text-files

The last word in every texts in testing.txt is "< /a>", I `echo` out the the word and it seems to be no problem, but when I `echo` out in the `for` loop, cmd gave me this error : *"The system cannot find the file specified."*
I know the problem is on the "<" and ">" sign, it stands for redirection, that's how the error created. How am I going to make cmd think I'm working with a string instead of redirection?

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "remove_char=< /a>"
echo !remove_char!

for /f "skip=2 tokens=6*" %%a in (testing.txt) do (
    set "string=%%a %%b"
    set string=!string:%remove_char%=!
    echo !string!

)

pause >nul
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass redirect symbols (< and >) to a Windows batch file function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406151/how-to-pass-redirect-symbols-and-to-a-windows-batch-file-function)

Comment: try with `set "string=!string:%remove_char%=!"`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use < and > symbols as variables you have to change them to ^< or ^>

Otherwise they will be treated as Input or Output!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can replace this line

```
set string=!string:%remove_char%=!
```

with

```
for %%i in (!remove_char!) do (set string=!string:%%i=!)
```